# How to extract .gpx data with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, extract, gpx

I would like to extract data from a GPX file in Node.js. (highest altitude, arrival/departure times, etc.).
I have looked around but there is not much information and I don't know what to do.
I would appreciate it if you could tell me what to do.
I am Japanese, so I apologize if my grammar is not correct.
Here is a GPX file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<gpx version="1.1" creator="GPS Visualizer https://www.gpsvisualizer.com/" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd">
<trk>
  <name>2021-10-03-XNA-NMQ-01</name>
  <desc>2021-10-03</desc>
  <trkseg>
    <trkpt lat="35.5773833" lon="137.41065">
      <ele>1024.0</ele>
      <time>2021-10-03T01:37:22Z</time>
    </trkpt>
    <trkpt lat="35.5773833" lon="137.41065">
      <ele>1024.0</ele>
      <time>2021-10-03T01:37:23Z</time>
    </trkpt>
    <trkpt lat="35.5773833" lon="137.41065">
      <ele>1024.0</ele>
      <time>2021-10-03T01:37:24Z</time>
    </trkpt>
    <trkpt lat="35.5773833" lon="137.41065">
      <ele>1024.0</ele>
      <time>2021-10-03T01:37:25Z</time>
    </trkpt>
    <trkpt lat="35.5773833" lon="137.41065">
      <ele>1024.0</ele>
      <time>2021-10-03T01:37:26Z</time>
    </trkpt>
    <trkpt lat="35.5774" lon="137.4106667">
      <ele>1024.0</ele>
      <time>2021-10-03T01:37:27Z</time>
    </trkpt>
    <trkpt lat="35.5774" lon="137.4106667">
      <ele>1024.0</ele>
      <time>2021-10-03T01:37:28Z</time>
    </trkpt>
    <trkpt lat="35.5774" lon="137.4106667">
      <ele>1025.0</ele>
      <time>2021-10-03T01:37:29Z</time>
    </trkpt>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------omission
  </trkseg>
</trk>
</gpx>
```

Comment: Did you look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/gpxparser ? It's just one of [many](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=gpx)

Comment: [This can probably help](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gpxparser).

Comment: @ITgoldman Yes.
I have looked into this.
I am ashamed to say that there is very little information on GPXperser.js and I have no idea how to use it.
I was able to load the file, but I don't know how to extract information from it.

Comment: [link]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72812741/how-to-extract-trkpt-object-information-from-gpx-parser-js-in-node-js) This is my past post.
I'd love for you to take a look at this one too if you'd like.

Comment: It's worth learning how to use npm packages.

Comment: @ITgoldman Ah, yes.
I don't know much about npm, so I'll look into it. Thanks for your help.